# Stopping a macports installed mysql daemon

Tags: macports, launchd, mysql

I'm trying to reset my root password on a macports installed MySQL on OS X. But none of the ways to do this that I can find works, for various reasons. One reason common to all is that I can't stop the mysql deamon.

As I understand it, I should be able to stop it with

```
sudo launchctl stop org.macports.mysql5
```

Which makes absolutely no difference. No error message, nothing. Is launchd really this sucky, or do I misuse it? Reasonably it should give me an error when it fails, but nope, nothing.

Trying to kill the processes with kill -9 just makes them restart again, so that doesn't work either.

I also tried

```
sudo launchctl unload org.macports.mysql5
```

But that gives me this error:

```
launchctl: Couldn't stat("org.macports.mysql5"): No such file or directory
```

(And I must confess I don't understand what "Unload configuration files and/or directories" means, which is what the Unload command apparently does according to the little docs I can find).

So, what now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct answer is

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
```

And you start it with

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql5.plist
```

Thanks to kh13org for the pointer.

Comment: The file name may be slightly different.  For example, on my system, the name is `/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.mysql55-server.plist`.